# Reverse proxy for a REST web service using ADFS/AD and WebApi

Tags: ios, rest, proxy, wif, adfs

I need to implement a reverse proxy for a REST webservice behind a firewall. The reverse proxy should authenticate against an enterprise ADFS 2.0 server, preferably using claims in .net 4.5.  The clients will be a mix of iOS, Android and web. I’m completely new to this topic; I’ve tried to implement the service as a REST service using WebApi, WIF and the new Identity and Access control in VS 2012, with no luck. I have also tried to look into Brock Allen’s Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45, however then my head was spinning so I didn’t see the difference between it and Windows Identity Foundation with the Identity and Access control.

So I think I need to step back and get some advice on how to do this.
There are several ways to this, as far as I understand it.

1. In hardware. Set up our Citrix Netscaler as a reverse proxy. I have no idea how to do that, however if it’s a good solution I can always hire someone who knows…
2. Do it in the webserver, like IIS. I haven’t tried it; do not know if it will work.
3. Create a web service to do it.
   3.1 Implement it as a SOAP service using WCF. As I understand it ADFS do not support REST so I have to use SOAP. The problem is mobile device do not like SOAP, neither do I… However if it’s the best way, I have to do it.
   3.2 Use Azure Access Control Service. It might work, however the timing is not good. Our enterprise is considering several cloud options, and us jumping on the azure wagon on our own might not be the smartest thing to do right now. However if it is the only options, we can do it. I just prefer not to use it right now.

Right now I feel there are too many options, and I do not know which one will work. If someone can point me in the right directions, which path to pursue, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this? I am also looking for same solution.

Comment: I wrote it all by myself as a webservice in asp.net. I call ADFS using active federation on the mobile device, sends the SAML token to the proxy where I convert it to Json Web Token in the reverse proxy (smaller). I check for the token in (asp.net) HTTP message handler. If the token is OK it redirects the request to the "walled" service, if not it returns a 401 not authorized. (The long answer is an article by itself.)

Comment: I'd be interested in that article ;P - Looking at similar options myself. Wondering how you did the redirecting part; I'm trying to use HttpMessageHandler with Web API to do the reverse proxy by adding credentials to the request before sending to the backend, but I am bumping in to some authentication issues.

Comment: Sorry dropped out of here for some months. If you still have problems: What autentications issus do you have? Problems authentication with ADFS or problem validating the SAML token in your reverse proxy?